# Google chrome established a extra tcp connection?

Tags: qt, google-chrome, http, networking

I am learning how to write a http application with Qt, and I test my program with Google Chrome, here is my code:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include "server.h"

Server::Server(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(m_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));
}

void Server::start()
{
    m_server->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 3000);
}

void Server::onNewConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "New Connection established!";
    if (m_server->hasPendingConnections())
    {
        QTcpSocket* socket = m_server->nextPendingConnection();
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    }
}

void Server::onReadyRead()
{
    QObject *object = sender();
    QTcpSocket* socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(object);
    qDebug() << socket->readAll();
    socket->write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
    socket->close();
}
```

By default, browser request URL we typed and /favicon.ico when requesting a website, however, in my console, I found I got the log:

```
New Connection established!
"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:3000\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,ja;q=0.5\r\nCookie: Webstorm-bd646432=4c22f08e-220c-4b65-9fcc-802b1ecc654c\r\n\r\n"
New Connection established!
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:3000\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8\r\nReferer: http://localhost:3000/\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,ja;q=0.5\r\nCookie: Webstorm-bd646432=4c22f08e-220c-4b65-9fcc-802b1ecc654c\r\n\r\n"
New Connection established!
```

I don't know what is this connection do, because it has empty http packet payload.